# Can't use sets with Image types?

Tags: python, image, arraylist, set, opencv

I am using the `pyautogui` library and I want to save my screenshots in a list that doesn't have duplicates. The type is an `Image` format which makes it unhashable. Is there any way to resolve this to where I can use sets with images?

The error message I get is `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Image'`.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
x = 1
pictures = []
check = []
while True:
    image = pyautogui.screenshot("image" + str(x) + '.png')
    check.append(image)
    print(len(check) != len(set(check)))
    x+=1
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: edit question, remove ``` and use button `{}` to correctly format code

Comment: Thanks khelwood I have trouble trying to format the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hash value for images by using the `hashlib` module and manually adding each one to the set. I don't have `pyautogui` installed, so used the `PIL` module instead which also provides a function for getting screenshots.

```
import hashlib
#import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

x = 1
pictures = []
image_hashes = set()  # Empty set.

for i in range(10):  # Do a limited number for testing.
#    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image = ImageGrab.grab()

    # Compute an image hash value.
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    h.update(image.tobytes())
    image_hash = h.digest()

    if image_hash not in image_hashes:
        pictures.append(image)
        image_hashes.add(image_hash)
#        image.save("image" + str(x) + '.png')  # Save image file.
        x += 1

    time.sleep(2)

print(len(pictures), 'unique images obtained')
```

Comment: Thanks! Yea its a lot more accurate on identifying the differences between images using hashes.